# Lua - Check if string contains valid characters

Tags: string, lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to check whether or not all chars in my string are either one of these numbers: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 OR a decimal point and whether they contain spaces or not. I'm using this piece of code but it's not working and I can't figure out why:

```
    print("Confirming added item")
    local validAmountString = true
    print(addScreen.amountTxtField.text)
    for i = 1, #addScreen.amountTxtField.text do
        local c = addScreen.amountTxtField.text:sub(i,i)
        print("Char " .. i .. " in the amount textflied is " .. c)
        if c == "0" or c == "1" or c == "2" or c == "3" or c == "4" or c == "5" or c == "6" or c == "7" or c == "8" or c == "9" or c == "." then
            validAmountString = true
        else
            validAmountString = false
        end
        print(validAmountString)
    end
    if string.gsub(addScreen.nameTxtField.text, "%s+", "") ~= "" and string.gsub(addScreen.amountTxtField.text, "%s+", "") ~= "" and validAmountString == true then
        --Proceed...
    end
```

The spaces part is working, but for some reason, when I try to check whether validAmountString == true in my if statement, it stops working. The validAmountString returns the correct boolean value according to my print statement though.

Any help? :)

Comment: please provide the input string

Comment: I've tried a lot of them. It's a value that the user fills in. I'm getting the correct boolean value for my the input (i.e. "200" will result in true). But even if it's true, it doesn't passes my if statement.

Comment: So you are trying to see if the string contains a valid number or not? If that's your actual question, please edit your question.

Comment: Or a decimal point. I feel like my question gives a solid first look about what this topic is going to be about. Checking the string for individual characters.

Comment: I think your question is currently an XY problem. So you want two valid types of input strings: 1. integer number, 2. number with a fractional part separated by a decimal point. In either no other characters are allowed. Lua's builtin `tonumber()` does that.

Comment: I'm not really following you on that one. Isn't there just a way to see if the string doesn't contain any characters except a decimal point or numbers?

Comment: [The XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You are asking if a string contains only numbers or the decimal point. Are you sure you don't really want to know if the string contains a valid number? Is a string with two decimal points valid? `tonumber()` returns the number represented by the string only if there is a valid number and any number of leading or trailing spaces, it returns `nil` otherwise. From that you can check to see if there is actually a number in the string.

Comment: Hi ktb, I got my program running because of you. You, and all others, were a massive help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to go about this would be string.find

```
local validAmountString = not addScreen.amountTxtField.text:find( "[^%d%.]" )
```

I'm afraid I can't tell why validAmountString is not true, but you don't have to compare boolean values.

```
if (validAmountString) then
--is equivilent to
if (validAmountString == true) then
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for shortening my code! But I still don't get why it's not passing the if statement when it's clearly true...

Comment: what he's doing here is: if there is any character in the text that is not a digit or a dot, the result is false, otherwise it is true. So does not have to check every character to be valid. He simply checks if any invalid is present
I inverted his result btw as the original version was not correct.

Comment: I don't really get what the "and false or true" thing is doing at the end. I never used it like that.

Comment: a = b and c or d will assign c to a if b is true, else it will asign d.

So if the result of string.find is not nil, validAmountString will be false, otherwise true. Read this: http://lua-users.org/wiki/TernaryOperator

Comment: Woops, so the correct boolean isn't being assigned to the var with the suggested line of code: "local validAmountString = addScreen.amountTxtField.text:find("[%d%.]") and false or true". It returns true for strings like "fdsdfs" as well.

Comment: you are missing ^ in your pattern! Find will then return nil if it cannot find a number or a dot which results in true for "fdsdfs"!

Comment: true and false or true ==> true;
false and false or true ==> true;
Not only does it not work, it's a bad way of doing things when we have the 'not' operator.

Answer (score 0):

For checking your strings refer to KingOfGamesYami's answer. He's using something called string patterns btw. Check the Lua reference http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1 for details.

"[^%d%.]" matches every character that not a digit or a dot. So if find returns something but nil, your string is invalid

For why your program isn't working as is (in case you want to stick to your complicated way:

You check every character of your string. If it is a number or a dot you asign true, if it's not you asign false.

So let's say you have "12A3" as a string.
Then the final value of validAmountString is true because the last character is a number. So you assign true 2 times, then false for the "A" and after that you asign true again. You mess up your total result.

What you should do here is either assign `validAmountString = validAmountString and true`, else `validAmountString = false` so you can never overwrite a `false`, once set.

The even better and more efficient way would be to simply stop your check once you've hit an invalid character. There is no need to check further characters if you find one invalid.
So simply add a `break` after `validAmountString = false`

Comment: Hi Piglet, I'm still trying to figure this out. But if I'd use KingOfGamesYami's solution, wouldn't it just assign the var to true once it finds one of the allowed numbers? Because I don't just need one of the chars to be valid, I need all of them. Also, my validAmountString is true but it still doesn't pass in my if statement and I just can't figure out why :/

Comment: see commend above

Comment: If he was to use this approach, he shouldn't set the value to true in the loop at all.  Once you hit a value that's incorrect, set it to false and break the loop (as you said in the last paragraph).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the loop to check whether it does or does not have valid characters.

You can simply do tonumber(string). It will return nil if there is any character other than a digit in the string.